# Resque - Can be used to execute Rake Tasks?

Tags: ruby, cucumber, rake, resque

I'm studying the possibilitie of using Resque in order to store rake tasks as jobs, and executing them later across multiple workers. Is this possible? I've already read the documentation for redis+resque, and tried to search examples of someone doing this, without success.

The rake tasks that I would like to execute as jobs, would fire cucumber+selenium to perform some web automation tests, that takes some time to complete.

Thanks in Advance!
Rodrigo.

Comment: yes as per my knowledge,`Rake::Task["task_name"].invoke` write this in perform and check

Comment: Yes, it is working that way! Thanks Amar.

Comment: @adids Could you please tell use the requirement of running rake can it be done via a cron or whenever gem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Amar told, using the invoke worked just fine.

Comment: Sound like a question to me please edit the question dont answer it as what  your answering is not a answer in any sense